# Clipping wrong results in C++ DIRECTX 11

Tags: directx11

Im trying to do some clipping but having some weird results. The triangle is not getting clipped how it should be. Here are some images.
The second image is how it should.

video of what is happen [VIDEO OF WHAT IS HAPPENING](http://recordit.co/SMwApJUYbD)

What is wrong with my code that is making the triangle wrong way.

CLIPPING ALGORITHM

```
ClipVertex( const Vector3& end )
{
    float BCend = mPlane.Test(end);
    bool endInside = ( BCend >= 0.0f );

    if (!mFirstVertex)
    {
        // if one of the points is inside
        if ( mStartInside || endInside )
        {
            // if the start is inside, just output it
            if (mStartInside)
                mClipVertices[mNumVertices++] = mStart;

            // if one of them is outside, output clip point
            if ( !(mStartInside && endInside) )
            {
                float t;
                Vector3 output;
                if (endInside)
                {
                    t = BCend/(BCend - mBCStart);
                    output =  end - t*(end - mStart);
                }
                else
                {
                    t = mBCStart/(mBCStart - BCend);
                    output = mStart + t*(end - mStart);
                }
                mClipVertices[mNumVertices++] = output;
            }
        }
    }
    mStart = end;
    mBCStart = BCend;
    mStartInside = endInside;
    mFirstVertex = false;

}
```

PLANE EQUATION

```
Plane clipPlane( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
```

In directx 11 in a Left Handed system

Comment: You should be able to delete the question, see [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).